# Pine Script: Updating Entry Orders

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My strategy sets a limit order at a moving average when a set of conditions are meant

Sometimes this can be considerably above / below the current price

I would like to have the limit price update at the end of every bar to the new MA price

Does anybody know if this is doable with pine-script v5?

Here is the code. I'm only focused on longs at the moment.

Appreciate the help

**Edited to include the full code**

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SQUEEZE CODE WITHOUT PLOTS
length = input.int(20, "TTM Squeeze Length")
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//BOLLINGER BANDS
BB_mult = input.float(2.0, "Bollinger Band STD Multiplier")
BB_basis = ta.sma(close, length)
dev = BB_mult * ta.stdev(close, length)
BB_upper = BB_basis + dev
BB_lower = BB_basis - dev
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//DEFINE EMA's
ema1 = ta.ema(close, 8)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, 21)
ema3 = ta.ema(close, 34)
ema4 = ta.ema(close, 55)
ema5 = ta.ema(close, 89)
ema6 = ta.ema(close, 250)
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//KELTNER CHANNELS
KC_mult_high = input.float(1.0, "Keltner Channel #1")
KC_mult_mid = input.float(1.5, "Keltner Channel #2")
KC_mult_low = input.float(2.0, "Keltner Channel #3")
KC_basis = ta.sma(close, length)
devKC = ta.sma(ta.tr, length)
KC_upper_high = KC_basis + devKC * KC_mult_high
KC_lower_high = KC_basis - devKC * KC_mult_high
KC_upper_mid = KC_basis + devKC * KC_mult_mid
KC_lower_mid = KC_basis - devKC * KC_mult_mid
KC_upper_low = KC_basis + devKC * KC_mult_low
KC_lower_low = KC_basis - devKC * KC_mult_low
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SQUEEZE CONDITIONS
NoSqz = BB_lower < KC_lower_low or BB_upper > KC_upper_low //NO SQUEEZE: GREEN
LowSqz = BB_lower >= KC_lower_low or BB_upper <= KC_upper_low //LOW COMPRESSION: BLACK
MidSqz = BB_lower >= KC_lower_mid or BB_upper <= KC_upper_mid //MID COMPRESSION: RED
HighSqz = BB_lower >= KC_lower_high or BB_upper <= KC_upper_high //HIGH COMPRESSION: ORANGE
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SETUP
setup = BB_lower >= KC_lower_mid or BB_upper <= KC_upper_mid ? 1 : 0
setupSum = math.sum(setup, 8)
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//BREAKOUT
breakOut = BB_lower < KC_lower_low or BB_upper > KC_upper_low ? 1 : 0
breakOutSum = math.sum(breakOut, 2)
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//TRADING CONDITIONS
condition1 = setupSum >= 2 and breakOutSum >= 2
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (condition1 == true and close > ema4 and strategy.position_size == 0)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit = ema3)
```

Comment: Can you share the full code so that we can test and help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your pending order if you call `strategy.entry()` with the same `id` (`"Long"` in your case).

> **strategy.entry**
>
> It is a command to enter market position. If an order with the same ID
> is already pending, it is possible to modify the order. If there is no
> order with the specified ID, a new order is placed.

Or you can use the `strategy.order()` function.

> **strategy.order**
>
> It is a command to place order. If an order with the same ID is
> already pending, it is possible to modify the order. If there is no
> order with the specified ID, a new order is placed.

If you want to modify your order after your set of conditions are `true`, I would suggest you use a `var` flag to see if the order is placed.

```
var order_placed = false

if (condition1 == true and close > ema4 and strategy.position_size == 0)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit = ema3)
    order_placed := true

if (order_placed)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit = ema3)     // Update the limit price to the ema value
```

Don't forget to reset this flag (probably when you enter a trade).

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working well. Now I have to figure out how to combine long and short effectively.